# Minimize/Maximize Box greyed out in MFC Dialog editor

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have a MFC dialog (`CDialog`) that I would like to add a maximize button to *via* the Visual Studio 2019 Dialog Editor.

However, the Minimize/Maximize Box options in the properties window for the dialog (in the editor) are greyed out. I have changed the Border to Resizing, which work fine.

Why can't I enable Maximize Box property?

These are the properties for the dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for your dialog box to have either the "Maximize Box" or "Minimize Box" (or to customize whether either or both of these are present/enabled), that dialog **must** have a "System Menu".

From the screen-shot you have posted, it is apparent that yours does *not* have that option set.

So, to enable the "Maximize Box" or "Minimize Box" options, you must first enable the "System Menu" option (6 properties down from "Minimize Box").

Related reading: [Windows Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) (see the section on the `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` style).